# How to make smoother borders using Fragment shader in OpenGL?

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl

I have been trying to draw border of an Image with transparent background using OpenGL in Android. I am using Fragment Shader & Vertex Shader. ([From the GPUImage Library](https://github.com/cats-oss/android-gpuimage))

Below I have added Fig. A & Fig B.

[image: Fig A. with rough border]

Fig A.

[image: Fig B. with smooth border]

Fig B.

I have achieved Fig A. With the customised Fragment Shader. But Unable to make the border smoother as in Fig B. I am attaching the Shader code that I have used (to achieve rough border). Can someone here help me on how to make the border smoother?

Here is my Vertex Shader :

```
    attribute vec4 position;
    attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate;        
    varying vec2 textureCoordinate;
    
    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = position;
        textureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy;
    }
```

Here is my Fragment Shader :

I have calculated 8 pixels around the current pixel. If any one pixel of those 8 is opaque(having alpha greater than 0.4), It it drawn as a border color.

```
                precision mediump float;
                uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
                varying vec2 textureCoordinate;
                uniform lowp float thickness;
                uniform lowp vec4 color;

                void main() {
                    float x = textureCoordinate.x;
                    float y = textureCoordinate.y;
                    vec4 current = texture2D(inputImageTexture, vec2(x,y));

                    if ( current.a != 1.0 ) {
                        float offset = thickness * 0.5;
                        
                        vec4 top = texture2D(inputImageTexture, vec2(x, y - offset));
                        vec4 topRight = texture2D(inputImageTexture, vec2(x + offset,y - offset));
                        vec4 topLeft = texture2D(inputImageTexture, vec2(x - offset, y - offset));
                        vec4 right = texture2D(inputImageTexture, vec2(x + offset, y ));
                        vec4 bottom = texture2D(inputImageTexture, vec2(x , y + offset));
                        vec4 bottomLeft  = texture2D(inputImageTexture, vec2(x - offset, y + offset));
                        vec4 bottomRight = texture2D(inputImageTexture, vec2(x + offset, y + offset));
                        vec4 left = texture2D(inputImageTexture, vec2(x - offset, y ));
                        
                        if ( top.a > 0.4 || bottom.a > 0.4 || left.a > 0.4 || right.a > 0.4 || topLeft.a > 0.4 || topRight.a > 0.4 || bottomLeft.a > 0.4 || bottomRight.a > 0.4 ) {
                             if (current.a != 0.0) {
                                 current = mix(color , current , current.a);
                             } else {
                                 current = color;
                             }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    gl_FragColor = current;
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost on the right track.

The main algorithm is:

- Blur the image.
- Use pixels with opacity above a certain threshold as outline.

The main problem is the blur step. It needs to be a large and smooth blur to get the smooth outline you want. For blurring, we can use convolution filter [Kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)). And to achieve a large blur, we should use a large kernel. And I suggest using the [Gaussian Blur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur) distribution, as it is very well known and used.

---

The Overview of he Algorithm is:

For each fragment, we sample many locations around it. The samples are made in an N by N grid. We average them together using weights that follow a [2D Gaussian Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).
This results in a blurred image.

With the blurred image, we paint the fragments that have alpha greater than a threshold with our outline color. And, of course, any opaque pixels in the original image should also appear in the result.

---

On a sidenote, your solution is almost a blur with a 3 x 3 kernel (you sample locations around the fragment in a 3 by 3 grid). However, a 3 x 3 kernel won't give you the amount of blur you need. You need more samples (e.g. 11 x 11). Also, the weights closer to the center should have a greater impact on the result. Thus, uniform weights won't work very well.

---

Oh, and one more important thing:

One single shader to acomplish this is NOT the fastest way to implement this. Usually, this would be acomplished with 2 separate renders. The first one would render the image as usual and the second render would blur and add the outline. I assumed that you want to do this with 1 single render.

The following is a vertex and fragment shader that accomplish this:

Vertex Shader

```
varying vec2 vecUV;
varying vec3 vecPos;
varying vec3 vecNormal;

void main() {
    vecUV = uv * 3.0 - 1.0;
    vecPos = (modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0)).xyz;
    vecNormal = (modelViewMatrix * vec4(normal, 0.0)).xyz;

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * vec4(vecPos, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader

```
precision highp float;

varying vec2 vecUV;
varying vec3 vecPos;
varying vec3 vecNormal;

uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;


float normalProbabilityDensityFunction(in float x, in float sigma)
{
    return 0.39894*exp(-0.5*x*x/(sigma*sigma))/sigma;
}

vec4 gaussianBlur()
{
    // The gaussian operator size
    // The higher this number, the better quality the outline will be
    // But this number is expensive! O(n2)
    const int matrixSize = 11;
    
    // How far apart (in UV coordinates) are each cell in the Gaussian Blur
    // Increase this for larger outlines!
    vec2 offset = vec2(0.005, 0.005);
    
    const int kernelSize = (matrixSize-1)/2;
    float kernel[matrixSize];
    
    // Create the 1-D kernel using a sigma
    float sigma = 7.0;
    for (int j = 0; j <= kernelSize; ++j)
    {
        kernel[kernelSize+j] = kernel[kernelSize-j] = normalProbabilityDensityFunction(float(j), sigma);
    }
    
    // Generate the normalization factor
    float normalizationFactor = 0.0;
    for (int j = 0; j < matrixSize; ++j)
    {
        normalizationFactor += kernel[j];
    }
    normalizationFactor = normalizationFactor * normalizationFactor;
    
    // Apply the kernel to the fragment
    vec4 outputColor = vec4(0.0);
    for (int i=-kernelSize; i <= kernelSize; ++i)
    {
        for (int j=-kernelSize; j <= kernelSize; ++j)
        {
            float kernelValue = kernel[kernelSize+j]*kernel[kernelSize+i];
            vec2 sampleLocation = vecUV.xy + vec2(float(i)*offset.x,float(j)*offset.y);
            vec4 sample = texture2D(inputImageTexture, sampleLocation);
            outputColor += kernelValue * sample;
        }
    }
    
    // Divide by the normalization factor, so the weights sum to 1
    outputColor = outputColor/(normalizationFactor*normalizationFactor);
    
    return outputColor;
}


void main()
{
    // After blurring, what alpha threshold should we define as outline?
    float alphaTreshold = 0.3;
    
    // How smooth the edges of the outline it should have?
    float outlineSmoothness = 0.1;
    
    // The outline color
    vec4 outlineColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    
    // Sample the original image and generate a blurred version using a gaussian blur
    vec4 originalImage = texture2D(inputImageTexture, vecUV);
    vec4 blurredImage = gaussianBlur();
    
    
    float alpha = smoothstep(alphaTreshold - outlineSmoothness, alphaTreshold + outlineSmoothness, blurredImage.a);
    vec4 outlineFragmentColor = mix(vec4(0.0), outlineColor, alpha);
    
    gl_FragColor = mix(outlineFragmentColor, originalImage, originalImage.a);
}
```

This is the result I got:

[image: Result from outline algorithm.]

And for the same image as yours, with `matrixSize = 33`, `alphaTreshold = 0.05`

[image: Result from outline algorithm with question image.]

And to try to get crispier results we can tweak the parameters. Here is an example with `matrixSize = 111`, `alphaTreshold = 0.05`, `offset = vec2(0.002, 0.002)`, `alphaTreshold = 0.01`, outlineSmoothness = 0.00. Note that increasing `matrixSize` will heavily impact performance, which is a limitation of rendering this outline with only one shader pass.

[image: Result from outline algorithm with question image and smoother edges.]

I tested the shader on [this site](https://shader-factory.herokuapp.com/). Hopefully you will be able to adapt it to your solution.

Regarding references, I have used quite a lot of [this shadertoy example](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XdfGDH) as basis for the code I wrote for this answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It pretty much helped me. Can u also add some modification to make the border edges clean? compare with the my attached pictures. i.e can we make it anti alialised?

Comment: There is kinda of a limitation on doing it with 1 shader pass. We CAN make it cleaner by decreasing the `offset` and decreasing `alphaTreshold`. Also, `outlineSmoothness` is already an anti aliasing factor. BUT, change only that and you will see that the outline will get thinner and you will also need to increase `matrixSize` to get a larger outline. And that will make the shader super heavy and slow. In that scenario, I would be heavily inclined to try to achieve the result with more than 1 pass instead of only 1 render. -- I have added the example to the answer.

Comment: Okay. thanks.Any hint how can i achieve it using multi pass?

Answer (score 0):

In my filters, the smoothness is achieved by a simple boxblur on the border.. You have decided that alpha > 0.4 is a border. The value of alpha between 0-0.4 in surrounding pixels gives an edge. Just blur this edge with a 3x3 window to get the smooth edge.

```
                    if ( current.a != 1.0 ) {
                    // other processing
                    
                    if (current.a > 0.4) {
                        if ( (top.a < 0.4 || bottom.a < 0.4 || left.a < 0.4 || right.a < 0.4 
                             || topLeft.a < 0.4 || topRight.a < 0.4 || bottomLeft.a < 0.4 || bottomRight.a < 0.4 ) 
                        {
                             // Implement 3x3 box blur here
                             
                        }
                    }
    }
```

You need to tweak which edge pixels you blur. The basic issue is that it drops from an opaque to a transparent pixel - what you need is a gradual transition.

Another options is quick anti-aliasing. From my comment below - Scale up 200% and then scale down 50% to original method. Use nearest neighbour scaling. This technique is used for smooth edges on text sometimes.

Comment: Hi Moi, Thanks for the reply. I've tried blurring but it only makes the border thicker. If you notice in the above fig B. Border, there are some pixels which are opeque in Fig A but Transparent in Fig. B. If you strongly believe this is the only solution and & I'm doing something wong, Can you please share some snippet or something ? which can be helpful..

Comment: The 3x3 blur will not result in a large enough blur radius, thus not leading to the desired result.

Comment: You could try a quick anti-aliasing method. Scale up 200% and then scale down 50% to original method. Use quick, nearest neighbour scaling.